# iterate over a list of custom object scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I want to iterate over a list of student

**EDITED**

```
  case class Group(grp:Person*){
      val myList=grp.toList
  }

   trait Person
   case class Student(firstName: String, lastName: String) extends Person
   case class Emp(empName: String, empLastName: String) extends Person
   case class grp(group: List[Group])
   grp(List(Group(Student("a","b"),Emp("c","d")),
         Group(Student("e","f"),Emp("g","h"))))
```

1. I want to print first name and last name of Student and employee
2. Any other alternative to achieve this ..may be using tuples.

Comment: Did you try to compile your code?

Comment: sorry .I am editing it please

Comment: @Dima Edited the code

Comment: This will not be possible as-is without reflection. I think you could migrate the `firstName` and `lastName` fields to the `Person` trait, then a simple `flatMap` or `flatten` followed by `forEach` would do the job.

Comment: @Dima Any alternative to `Person*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make `firstName` and `lastName` members of the `Person`:

```
 trait Person {
   def firstName: String
   def lastName: String
 }
```

And also change the `Emp` definition for field names to match:

```
case class Emp(firstName: String, lastName: String) extends Person
```

Now, you can do something like:

```
 val groups = grp(...) 
 groups.flatMap(_.myList).foreach { p => 
     println(s"${p.firstName} ${p.lastName}")
 }
```

Comment: In actual use case there are many case class of different paranters type and i want to override to string to get the value out of it

Comment: If u also suggest any other way using tuples other any better method considetracked group  having different paranters as well as members. I am creating a fix message repeating group actually

Comment: If u also suggest any other way using tuples other any better method considetracked group  having different paranters as well as members. I am creating a fix message repeating group actually

Comment: No, tuples are bad. You don't want to use tuples. This is the best way. And it is less work to rename the fields to override `toString` (and you shouldn't really be overriding it for case classes).

Comment: Any alternative to vararush Person*

Comment: Not sure what kind of "alternative" you are looking for. `Seq[Person]`?
It's the same thing really ...

Comment: Yes  but any other way to do the same functionality .I may create  nested group I. Enjoy group inside another

Comment: Yeah, plenty of ways. You can also create a group of groups of groups, and wrap it around into a tuple with an iterator inside of it, that returns a future, that resolves to a list. Why not? The question is why you would want to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152189/discussion-between-coder25-and-dima).

Answer (score 0):

```
  grp(List(Group(Student("a","b"),Emp("c","d")),
    Group(Student("e","f"),Emp("g","h")))).group.map(a => a.myList.map(b => b match {
    case Student(x,y) => println(x+" "+y);
    case Emp(x,y) => println(x+" "+y);
  }))
```